# Application title for browser and home icon label

Tags: sencha-architect

I am using sencha touch 2 with sencha architect. I cannot find the GUI path to change the application title that is used when the app is shown in the browser or for the label of the home icon on iOs.

Anyway if I change the Title tag in the app.html, sencha architect overwrites the file with the default title. Sencha touch 2 is a very powerful product but the documentation is a little bit confused for me.

Thanks a lot

Comment: it is possible to change it opening the XDS project file...

Answer (score 1):

Select 'Application' in your Project Inspector. Change the 'name' of your application in the Config panel.

Comment: @Joost, that is not Application title, it is used as the Application's global namespace, look here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-cfg-name